# Include third party resource in chef

Tags: chef-infra

I am  trying use [chef-gsettings](https://github.com/MarkRoddy/chef-gsettings)

```rb
# ./cookbooks/my_cookbook/recipes/default.rb
include_recipe 'chef-gsettings'
```

Also uploaded it to Chef Server with

```sh
$ knife cookbook upload chef-gsettings
```

But bootstrap fails

```sh
$ knife bootstrap 192.168.1.88 -U user -i ~/.ssh/id --node-name node1 --sudo --run-list 'recipe[my_cookbook]' 
...
FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::RecipeNotFound: could not find recipe default for cookbook chef-gsettings
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you could see, [chef-gsettings](https://github.com/MarkRoddy/chef-gsettings) cookbook does not have any recipes in it. It just provides a *gsettings* resource to use in your cookbook.

But here you are including `chef-gsettings::default` recipe (providing only cookbook name and omitting recipe, means you include `::default` recipe).

```rb
# ./cookbooks/my_cookbook/recipes/default.rb
include_recipe 'chef-gsettings'
```

That's why the error.

```
FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::RecipeNotFound: could not find recipe default for cookbook chef-gsettings
```

You actually need to use *gsettings* resource in your recipe ([see Usage in readme](https://github.com/MarkRoddy/chef-gsettings#usage)):

```rb
# ./cookbooks/my_cookbook/recipes/default.rb
gsettings "org.gnome.desktop.interface" do
  option "monospace-font-name"
  value "Monospace 14"
  user "bob"
end
```

If this does not work, which is possible, because you imported this cookbook as 'chef-gsettings' and not as 'gsettings', you will need to use `chef-gsettings` resource:

```rb
# ./cookbooks/my_cookbook/recipes/default.rb
chef-gsettings "org.gnome.desktop.interface" do  # !!! this will not work, as Ruby does not allow `-` in method names
  [...]
end

# Try using this workaround instead:
declare_resource('chef-gsettings'.to_sym, "org.gnome.desktop.interface") do
  option "monospace-font-name"
  [...]
end
```

Comment: where `gsettings` resource files are supposed to be located?

Comment: They are in gsettings cookbook, you don't need to add them anywhere else.

Comment: I added `name "gsettings"` property under `chef-gsettings/metadata.rb` and `knife cookbook upload gsettings`,  also added it to my cookbook dependencies